# Update multiple SQL tables at once Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 SQL tables - One called "users" and another one called "history".

**The users table** have "id" primary key and "username" rows.

**The history table** have "id" primary key, "username" and "sport" row.

So when the user is logged in, the history joins the "username" from the 2 tables and shows the history correctly where the username equals the username from "users" table.

My problem is, that I have created a method that lets the user update his "username". This works, but will only update the "username" in users table. The result is that the user is not able to see the "history" after updateing the username. So my question is this:

Is there a way to update 2 tables at once? So the username will both be updated in "users" and "history" table?

I have added my "updateUserName()" method below:

```
public static void updateUserName(String userName, long id) throws SQLException {
        
        Connection connection = null;   
        PreparedStatement ps = null; 
        
        try {
            
            DB_Connection connect = new DB_Connection();
            connection=connect.get_Connection();
            
            String sql = "UPDATE users SET user_name = ? WHERE id = ?";
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            ps.setString(1, userName);
            ps.setLong(2, id);
            
            ps.executeUpdate();
            
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your structure is wrong. `History` table must store not `username` but its `id` from `users` table. *Is there a way to update 2 tables at once?* Yes, look for multiple-table UPDATE syntax in User Manual.

Comment: Not that it's a good idea, but you could also add a cascading foreign key to the ```history``` table.  But yes, I'd agree with @Akina and store the ```id``` everywhere else except the ```users``` table.

Comment: Thank you guys. I updated the tables so it would join on id from users and put a new row in history called "usersID".

Answer (score 0):

Update multiple SQL tables at once Java

Query:

update TN1, TN2 set TN1.CN=Value, TN2.CN=value where TN1.CN=TN2.CN and TN.CN=2;

Query Example :
update eco_mark,com_mark set eco_mark .emark=99,com_mark.emark=95 where eco_mark.id=com_mark.id and eco_mark.id=2;

**in java code**

```
  try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dgsuthi","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
        int i= st.executeUpdate("update eco_mark,com_mark set eco_mark .emark=99,com_mark.emark=95 where eco_mark.id=com_mark.id and eco_mark.id=2");
   if(i>0){
    System.out.print("hello Uthi");
   }
     
}catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
}
```